# Data.Map - why is there `takeWhileAntitone` but no `takeWhile`?

Tags: dictionary, haskell, containers

I'm confused by `Data.Map` API. I'm looking for a simple way to find a range of keys of the map at `log(n)` cost. This is a basic concept known as "binary search", and maybe "bisecting".

I see this strange `takeWhileAntitone` function where I need to provide an "antitone" predicate function. It's the first time I encounter this concept.

After reading Wikipedia on the topic, this seems to be simply saying that there may be only one place where the function changes from `True` to `False` when applied to arguments in key order. This fits a requirement for a binary search.

Since the API is documented in a strange (to me) language, I wanted to ask here:

- if my understanding is correct, and
- is there a reason these functions aren't called `bisect`, `binarySearch` or similar?

Comment: You're looking for `split` for your specific use case, or possibly `splitLookup` depending on if your range is inclusive.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I think the `*Antitone` functions are quite plausibly right for this purpose, unless you know something about the application that the rest of us don't. It all depends on exactly what information is needed.

Comment: "A range of keys for the map" suggests the OP is just looking for an intersection of the map with a range of keys [a, b] or the like, and split is explicitly designed for breaking the map into keys on one side of a range.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, `split` is for exclusive ranges on both sides of a specific key, which is removed if present. `spanAntitone` leaves all the entries in its results. So which you want depends on which behavior is useful to you. `spanAntitone` is, generally, more flexible, since it can do things like `spanAntitone isLeft`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Since the API is documented in a strange (to me) language, I wanted to ask here:
>
> - if my understanding is correct, and

Yes. `takeWhileAntitone` (and other similarly named variants in the library) is the function for doing binary search on keys. It's not named `takeWhile` because it does not work for any argument predicate, so if you're reviewing code, it serves as a reminder to check for that.

> - is there a reason these functions aren't called bisect, binarySearch or similar?

1. This name serves to distinguish variants `takeWhileAntitone`, `dropWhileAntitone`, `spanAntitone` that "do binary search" but with different final results.
2. `takeWhile` is a well-known name from Haskell's standard library (in `Data.List`).
3. In FP we like to distinguish the "what" from the "how". "binary search" is an algorithm ("how"). "take while" is also literally a "how", but its meaning is arguably more naturally connected to a "what" (the longest prefix of elements satisfying a predicate). In particular, the interpretation of "take while" as "longest prefix" doesn't rely on any assumption about the predicate.

Comment: Maps in the containers package are very definitely binary trees (Adams' trees/trees of bounded balance) and not finger trees.

Comment: Ah, oops, I worked too much on sequence!